# Flex 4 Circular path graident stroke for a Color Wheel component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, gradient, rgb, ellipse

I'm attempting to create a color wheel component in Flex 4 that will allow me to represent RGB and HSL data.  I'm doing so with a circular color wheel representing the various hues available to me and a rectangular gradient in the center of that which will represent the lightness and saturation fields

Currently I have the objects represented but I cannot determine the best way to fill them in.  I have no problem creating the gradient necessary in the center square, but I cannot get the outer ring to build a -circular- gradient.  It seems the only two native gradients in flex are linear and radial, but I need the gradient to linearly follow the path around the ellipse.  How would I make this possible?

Here's the attempt I've made thus far:

```
<s:Group>
    <s:Ellipse x="7" y="7" width="136" height="136">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke weight="14">
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0" color="0xFF0000"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.1647" color="0xFFFF00"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.3294" color="0x00FF00"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.4941" color="0x00FFFF"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.6588" color="0x0000FF"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.3529" color="0xFF00FF"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="1" color="0xFF0000"/>
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Ellipse>
    <s:Rect x="32" y="32" width="86" height="86">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
```

The colors and their ratios properly position the gradient I need from left to right but the end result comes up as such:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/10/flexo.png/

I would like the image to come up like this:  (screenshot from paint shop pro 8)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/687/psph.png/

(sorry for the links, but I don't have 10 rep yet so I can't post the images straight in the post)

(no, I haven't built the rectangle gradient yet, as it's colors are based off of the outer ring...I'm not worried about the rectangle just yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out finally

First, I utilized the code from Ryan Taylor of BoostWorthy.com that was brought up in this tutorial:
http://www.boostworthy.com/blog/?p=200

The trouble with this tutorial is that the color ranges do not get all of the possible hues available for my hue color wheel since he is using sine waves to calculate the angular color.  If you review the wikipedia article for Hue you can see that the color spectrum is not a sine wave but rather a simple blend of red green and blue.  Here is the graph that visually explains what I'm talking about:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HSV-RGB-comparison.svg

If you use sine waves instead the waves only peak at their maximum value *once* every 60 degrees...when the color value's slope needs to be constant during every 60 degrees (i.e. during one period each color will have a maximum value of 255 or a minimum value of 0 for the duration of that period)

This was brought up in the tutorial's posts as an issue with his code, but no one posted the resolution for it...Here's the actual resolution:

```
//Define our variables
var nRadians:Number;
var nColor:int = 0;
var nX:Number;
var nY:Number;
var nIX:Number;
var nIY:Number;     
var nR:Number;
var nG:Number;
var nB:Number;
// Calculate the thickness of the lines which draw the colors.
var iThickness:int = 1 + int(nRadius / 50); 

// Loop from '0' to '360' degrees, drawing lines from the center 
// of the wheel outward the length of the specified radius.
for(var i:int = 0; i < 360; i++)
{
    nRadians = i * (Math.PI / 180);

    var offset:Number = i;
    do 
    {
        offset = offset - 60;
    } while (offset >= 60)

    if (offset < 0) offset = offset + 60;

    var greenSlope:String = "up";
    var redSlope:String = "max";
    var blueSlope:String = "min";

    //GREEN-----------------
    if (i >= 60) greenSlope = "max";
    if (i > 180) greenSlope = "down";
    if (i >= 240) greenSlope = "min";
    //RED-------------------
    if (i > 60) redSlope = "down";
    if (i >= 120) redSlope = "min";
    if (i > 240) redSlope = "up";
    if (i >= 300) redSlope = "max";
    //BLUE------------------
    if (i > 120) blueSlope = "up";
    if (i >= 180) blueSlope = "max";
    if (i > 300) blueSlope = "down";

    var colorArr:Array = new Array(blueSlope,greenSlope,redSlope);
    var valueArr:Array = new Array(nB,nG,nR);
    var counter:int = 0;
    var bitRotation:int = 0;

    for each (var color:String in colorArr)
    {
        var value:Number = 0;
        var percentUpOffset:Number = ((100 / 60) * offset) / 100;
        var percentDownOffset:Number = ((100 / 60) * (60 - offset)) / 100;

        if (color == "max")  value = 255;
        if (color == "min")  value = 0;
        if (color == "up")   value = 255 * percentUpOffset;
        if (color == "down") value = 255 * percentDownOffset;

        valueArr[counter] = value << bitRotation;
        if (i == 0) trace(value);

        bitRotation = bitRotation + 8;  
        counter++;
    }

    nR = valueArr[2];
    nG = valueArr[1];
    nB = valueArr[0];

    // OR the individual color channels together.
    nColor = nR | nG | nB;

    // Calculate the coordinate in which the line should be drawn to.
    // (nIX / nIY is the inner start position of the ring
    nX = (nRadius * Math.cos(nRadians)) + DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    nY = (nRadius * Math.sin(nRadians)) + DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    nIX = ((nRadius - nHeight) * Math.cos(nRadians)) + DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    nIY = ((nRadius - nHeight) * Math.sin(nRadians)) + DEFAULT_RADIUS;

    //Draw the line
    var line:Line = new Line();
    var stroke:SolidColorStroke = new SolidColorStroke(nColor,iThickness);
    line.stroke = stroke;
    line.xFrom = nIX;
    line.xTo = nX;
    line.yFrom = nIY;
    line.yTo = nY;

    this.addElement(line);
}
```